# how to read docs file in laravel with text format using with phpword package

Tags: php, ms-word, laravel-5.4, docx, phpword

i wanted to know how to run docs file in laravel using with external package og phpword, need to read same format of docs file, this is readinga text but not correct format please help me somehow

here is controller code its not formatting proper

```
public  function view_file($file_name)
{
    $file_entries=Fileentry::all();

    $file=public_path('storage\\'.$file_name);

    $phpWord = IOFactory::createReader('Word2007')->load($file);

    if(method_exists($phpWord, 'getSections')) {
        foreach ($phpWord->getSections() as $section) {

            $body = '';

            if (method_exists($section, 'getElements')) {

                foreach ($section->getElements() as $element) {
                    if (method_exists($element, 'getText')) {
                        $body .= $element->getText();
                    }
                    if (class_exists(Text::class)) {
                        if (method_exists($element, 'getText')) {

                            if (class_exists(TextBreak::class)) {
                                $body .= '<br/>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (class_exists(TextBreak::class)) {
                $body .= '<br/>';
            }

            if (class_exists(Table::class)) {
                $body .= '<table border="2px">';
                if (method_exists($element, 'getRows')) {
                    $row = $element->getRows();
                    foreach ($row as $rows) {
                        $body .= '<tr>';
                        if (method_exists($element, 'getCell')) {
                            $cells = $rows->getCell();
                            foreach ($cells as $cell) {
                                $body .= '<td style="width:' . $cell->getWidth . '">';
                                $celements = $cell->getElements();
                                foreach ($celements as $celem) {
                                    if (class_exists(Text::class) == $celem) {
                                        $body .= $celem->getText();
                                    } else if (class_exists(TextRun::class) == $celem) {
                                        foreach ($celements as $text) {
                                            $body .= $text->getText();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                $body .= '</td>';
                            }
                        }
                        $body .= '</tr>';
                    }
                }
            }

            if (class_exists(TextBreak::class)) {
                $body .= '<br/>';
            }

            return view('doc_view', compact('body', 'file_entries'));
        }
    }
}
```